# thread_local и количество потоков

Tags: c++

Подскажите, можно ли считать, что доступ к переменной объявленной, как thread_local, будет пропорционально медленнее с ростом числа потоков, которые запускают код с этой переменной ?

Comment: Сам доступ? вряд ли, это же просто переменная в стеке потока, нет?

Comment: нет, у каждого потока будет своя версия такой переменной...

Comment: оно реализовывается обычно через специальное апи ОС. Я думаю, что можно реализовать такую переменную на стеку, но в линуксе и винде так не делают.

Comment: https://xakep.ru/2011/01/10/55570/  но я сильно сомневаюсь, что с ростом кол-ва потоков производительность сильно будет менятся.

Comment: а подумайте о более красивом решении. У потока есть 4-8 байт адреса tls массива, где просто по индексу (массив или мапа) можно доступится к переменной. И в таком случае не нужно ни синхронизации, ни дополнительных проблем

Comment: ну не нужно удалять комментарии. теперь мои комментарии выглядят как странные сироты

Comment: @KoVadim, да, я что то просто подумал, что глупость написал и решил удалилить.

Comment: @KoVadim комментарии вообще могут в любой момент (почти) бесследно исчезнуть, стоит это иметь в виду (и не переживать сильно).

Comment: я знаю. Но ... выглядит странно

Comment: @Fat-Zer А разве у каждого потока не свой стек?

Comment: @Mikhailo, свой, но `thread_local`-переменные хранятся не на стеке, а в локальном хранилище потока...

Comment: @KoVadim, больше комментарии удалять не буду. Я просто написал свое предположение, как мне думалось может грубо устроен этот thread_local, а потом увидел Вашу ссылку на xaker.ru/

Comment: @Fat-Zer Не знал. Думал, в стеке. А где об этом пишут? в стиандарте?

Comment: @Mikhailo, прямым текстом, скорее всего, ни где не сказано — стандарт обычно не опускается до  таких понятий как «стек вызовов», но `thread_local` — это по определению спецификатор класса хранения, такой же как `static` или как до c++11 был `auto` ... требования к классам хранения описаны в *6.7 [\[basic.stc\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc)*

Comment: @Fat-Zer В таком случае это вполне может быть именно стек потока...

Comment: @Mikhailo, под «стеком потока» обычно понимают то место, где поток хранит локальные переменные своих функций, а thread_local-переменные хранятся не там и структура для их хранения не является стеком...